# When i click button and show Full information on model popup

Tags: php, html, sql, model, popup

when i click button and show Full information on model popup

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
</button><!-- Modal -->
```

the information will be show model popup

Comment: Please explain your question or add your code

Comment: Show some code what you need and what you have made.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
</button><!-- Modal -->

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: i want to sent ID from this button <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
</button><!-- Modal -->

Comment: you want to assign an `id` to the button?

Comment: are you trying to open a modal popup ?

Comment: yes, @Hazard i want that

Comment: can see in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863294/how-can-i-get-data-from-this-html-to-query-in-sql/35863456#35863456

Comment: [This is answer and clear the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863294/how-can-i-get-data-from-this-html-to-query-in-sql/35863456#35863456)

Comment: The answer is follow link
[This is clear question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863294/how-can-i-get-data-from-this-html-to-query-in-sql/35863456#35863456)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
</button><div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/17948/)</kbd>

Comment: YES, but i want to sent ID onclick too

Comment: where do you need to send ? Explain your functionality..what do you need to do by sending id ?

Comment: some ID from database onclick
and like a i press the Full View button to see the full information